# im having issue about summary of 2 matrices

Tags: python, matrix

Why does my result of sum not sum 2 matrices, it only put variable in matrix1 and marix2 to become a one integer?

```
row = int(input("enter for row:")) 
kol = int(input("enter for column :"))     
matrix1 = [[input("enter the element of matrix 1:")for j in range(row)]for i in range (kol)]
matrix2 = [[input("enter the element of matrix 2:")for j in range(row)]for i in range (kol)]
sum=[[0 for i in range(kol)]for j in range(row)]
print("matrix1")

for j in range(row):

 for i in range(kol):
    print (format(matrix1[j][i],"<3"), end="")
print()
print ("matrix2")
   for j in range(row):
       for i in range(kol):
    print(format(matrix2[j][i],"<3"), end="")
print()

print("sum matrix")
   for j in range(kol):
       for i in range(row):
    sum[j][i]=matrix1[j][i]+matrix2[j][i]
 print(format(sum[j][i],"<3"),end="")
 print()
```

Comment: By the way, on Line 2, that should be "enter for _column_" ;)

Comment: there's quite a few syntax errors for instance you put in `sum` instead of `sumv` in the last loop. You also havent converted the input to either a `float` or and `int` so your addition will just give you a list of `string`s. Besides that, your indention is all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code works fine but there are a few obvious errors for instance you put in `sum` instead of `sumv` in the last loop. You also haven't converted the input to either a float or and int so your addition will just give you a list of strings. Besides that, your indention is all over the place. Below is a tidied up version of your code followed by the input & output of a test case. It works just fine you just need to take more care when typing it up.

```
row = int(input("enter for row: ")) 
kol = int(input("enter for column: ")) 
    
matrix1 = [[float(input("enter the element of matrix 1: ")) for j in range(row)] for i in range (kol)]
matrix2 = [[float(input("enter the element of matrix 2: ")) for j in range(row)] for i in range (kol)]
sumv    = [[0 for i in range(kol)] for j in range(row)]

print("\nmatrix1")
for j in range(row):
    for i in range(kol):
        print (format(matrix1[j][i], "<3"), end=" ")
    print(" ")
print("\n")

print ("matrix2")
for j in range(row):
    for i in range(kol):
        print(format(matrix2[j][i], "<3"), end=" ")
    print(" ")
print("\n")

print("sum matrix")
for j in range(kol):
    for i in range(row):
        sumv[j][i] = matrix1[j][i] + matrix2[j][i]
        print(format(sumv[j][i], "<3"), end=" ")
    print(" ")
print(" ")
```

[image: Test case...]